# Doubly infinite matrices $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j=\infty}^{\infty}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j=\infty}^{\infty}$, where
$$
\|A\|:=\sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\sup_{j}|a_{j,j+r}|<\infty.
$$

I want to show that for all matrices $\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\|B\|$. I obverse that 
$$
(AB)_{i,j}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{i,k}b_{k,j}=c_{i,j}
$$

Hence,
\begin{align}
\|AB\|&=\sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\sup_{j}|c_{j,j+r}|\\
&=\sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\sup_{j}|\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{j,k}b_{k,j+r}|\\
&\leq \sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\sup_{j}|a_{j,k}b_{k,j+r}|\\
&\leq \sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\sup_{j}|a_{j,k}|\cdot|b_{k,j+r}|\\
&\leq ?
\end{align}

How can I finish this proof? Any hints?

Comment: I feel like this norm would be more interesting for a doubly infinite Vector: Sum sup |a_j-a_(j+r)|/r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\| A B \|
=
\sum_r \sup_j |\sum_k a_{j,k} b_{k,j+r}|
$

$
\leq
\sum_r \sum_k |a_{j(r),k}| |b_{k,j(r)+r}|
$
 --- $j(r)$ is where the $\sup$ is attained (possibly up to $\epsilon$...)

$
=
\sum_r \sum_k |a_{j(r),k+j(r)}| |b_{k+j(r),j(r)+r}|
$

$
=
\sum_k \sum_r |a_{j(r),k+j(r)}| |b_{k+j(r),j(r)+r}|
$

$
\leq
\sum_k \sup_j |a_{j,k+j}|
\sum_r |b_{k+j(r), j(r) + r}|
$

$
\stackrel{r = r' + k}{=}
\sum_k \sup_j |a_{j,k+j}|
\sum_{r'} |b_{k+j(r'+k), k+j(r'+k) + r'}|
$

$
\leq
\sum_k \sup_j |a_{j,k+j}|
\sum_{r'} \sup_\ell |b_{\ell, \ell + r'}|
$

Comment: When does e uality hold?

Comment: @JacobWakem: that probably deserves a separate question

Comment: Apparently you have to gain for what you learn.